# Django, How to render page just for once

Tags: django

I have a view method.

```
def create_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post.objects.create(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'baseapp/create_new_second.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = PostCreateForm
        return render(request, 'baseapp/create_new_first.html', {'form': form})
```

and It's urls.py, there is

```
re_path(r'^create/new/$', views.create_new, name='create_new'),
```

So, html file is like(It's loading `baseapp/create_new_second.html`):

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}<button type="submit" id="create">Create</button></form>
```

If I get `baseapp/create_new_second.html` by click `create` button on `baseapp/create_new_first.html`, there is some creating of Post object. (views.py- `post = Post.objects.create(user=request.user)`)

But after rendered `baseapp/create_new_second.html`, If I browser page refresh by `f5` or refresh button, There maybe recurring of this part:

`post = Post.objects.create(user=request.user)`

The result is, that everytime when I refresh the page on `'baseapp/create_new_second.html'`, new post is generated everytime.

How can I prevent it?

I want to prevent `click f5`-`new post generation` loop.